# BigQuery: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run my query on real tables I get the error:

`Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN`

Here is the exact query that I am running:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN addresses LIKE '%,%'
THEN
(
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT address) addresses
FROM VW_CLEAN.TABLE_1
WHERE member_id = el.member_id
AND eligible_month < el.eligible_month
GROUP BY member_id, eligible_month
ORDER BY eligible_month DESC 
LIMIT 1
) 
END AS address,
eligible_month, 
member_id
FROM
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT address) addresses, eligible_month, member_id FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT address, eligible_month, member_id
        FROM VW_CLEAN.TABLE_1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT address, eligible_month, member_id
        FROM VW_CLEAN.TABLE_2
    )
    GROUP BY eligible_month, member_id
) el
WHERE member_id IS NOT NULL
AND eligible_month IS NOT NULL
```

But when I prepared the same query but for the test data using "WITH AS", it runs without the error.

```
#standardSQL
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT "201905" AS month, "11111" AS member, "123" AS address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "201903" AS month, "11111" AS member, "234" AS address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "201902" AS month, "11111" AS member, "345" AS address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "201902" AS month, "22222" AS member, "456" AS address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "201901" AS month, "22222" AS member, "567" AS address
),
table_2 AS (
  SELECT "201904" AS month, "11111" AS member, "678" AS address
)

SELECT 
a.member,
a.month,
(
  SELECT STRING_AGG(address) address
  FROM table_1
  WHERE member = a.member
  AND month < a.month
  GROUP BY member, month
  ORDER BY month DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) AS previous_address
FROM
(
    SELECT STRING_AGG(address) address, month, member
    FROM
    (
        SELECT month, member, address
        FROM table_1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT month, member, address
        FROM table_2
    )
    GROUP BY month, member
    HAVING member = '11111' AND month = '201905'
) a
```

So what is the difference between real tables and tables created using "WITH AS"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact answer to your question, however, I can say your query is not one of the best practices.

I'd like to learn more about your table1 and table2 to have a better query, but for now, I'll treat it as a single table to get the previous address for a member.

So you can use window functions to get the previous value of a user.
I prepared an example query for you, I can make it better if you can give more details about your tables and your purpose.

```
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT "201905" AS month, "11111" AS member, "123" AS address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "201903" AS month, "11111" AS member, "234" AS address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "201902" AS month, "11111" AS member, "345" AS address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "201902" AS month, "22222" AS member, "456" AS address
  UNION ALL
  SELECT "201901" AS month, "22222" AS member, "567" AS address
),
table_2 AS (
  SELECT "201904" AS month, "11111" AS member, "678" AS address
)
SELECT 
  *,
  lag(address) over (partition by member order by month) previous_address,
  last_value(t1_address ignore nulls) over (partition by member order by month rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as previous_t1_address
FROM 
(
    SELECT month, member, address, address as t1_address
    FROM table_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT month, member, address, null
    FROM table_2
);
```

Comment: I have added the exact query that I am running in the description. Please take a look and help, thanks.

Comment: The problem is you shouldn't use correlated queries in BigQuery. It's a bad practice. BigQuery is not designed for that usage.
Also, for your use case correlated queries are not the best way even in the other database engines. There are window functions to solve your problem, and you should be using them.
Why don't you want to use the query above? It works as intended already, and if it doesn't, we can fix it. Just provide input and output data for your problem.

Comment: The results from "el" subquery can be like:
addresses: address1, address2
member: 11111
eligible_month: 201906

So when I get results like "%,%" in addresses, I want to take the address from the previous month. But the previous month is not always 201905, but may be even 201802.
Let's imagine that the previous record for this member is:
addresses: address3
member: 11111
eligible_month: 201802

So the output of the whole query should be:
addresses: address3
member: 11111
eligible_month: 201906

Comment: Have you tried my query? Where does it fail? It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation.

> FROM clause aliases are not visible to subqueries in the same FROM
>   clause. Subqueries in a FROM clause cannot contain correlated
>   references to other tables in the same FROM clause.

In your case, you are using the fields **el.member_id** and **el.eligible_month** and based on the message mentioned above, the table **el** is not visible to subqueries.

In [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#from_clause_aliases) you can find more examples about invalid correlate subqueries.

However, the best practice should be the WITH statement.